# ¿Como soluciono este problema de Android?

Tags: java, android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Al querer ejecutar mi aplicación me aparece este error en el IDE, me podrían decir como solucionarlo por favor.

Comment: muestra el error como texto, la imagen no ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco tuve ese problema.
Lo que tenes que hacer es bajar el [SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) y luego copiar el archivo adb que biene en el archivo que descargas y pegarlo en en tu SDK local. 
Al parecer el antivirus detecta este archivo como virus y lo elimina. 
Te dejo un video con la solución que a mi me funciono donde hace los pasos que te describo. 
[Solucion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeZKmxt4jkI)

Answer (score -1):

Parece que en tu instalación no tenes instalado el SDK Platform Tools, donde uno de sus componentes es el ADB ( Android Debug Bridge ) necesario para comunicarte con tu device.

Para comprobar si esta instalado y si no lo tenes podes instalarlo, entrando a : Preferences-> System Settings -> Android SDK y ahí elegir el SDK Tools y darle check al Android SDK Platform-Tools y el Android SDK Tools.

También podes ingresar dandole al icono del SDK Manager en el Android Studio.

Espero que esto solucione tu inconveniente.

Saludos,